# Why sometimes it opens a new window and sometimes in the same page when clicking a "target='_top'" link?

Tags: html

I have noticed that most Google Adsense ads are leading to a new window. But sometimes I found it also opens the target page in the same window.

The link code are always like

`<a href="xxxx" target="_top" ....`

Why is this happening?

Thanks,